# Is TTL for Cassandra counter column family supported?

Tags: cassandra, counter, hector, ttl

Does Cassandra support TTL for the Counter column family?

Specifically we use Hector as a client to Cassandra and I didn't find any API receiving TTL as a parameter. At least `HFactory.createCounterColumn` doesn't have TTL argument.

Answer (score 8):

No. TTL expiration does not exist for counter columns. See [CASSANDRA-2103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2103) for background on why this feature doesn't make sense for Cassandra counter columns.