# Cassandra "default_time_to_live" property is not deleting data

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, ttl

I've created a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metrics_second(
  timestamp timestamp,
  value counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((timestamp))
) WITH default_time_to_live=1;
```

And inserted some data like:

```
UPDATE metrics_second SET value = value + 1 WHERE timestamp = '2015-01-22 17:43:55-0800';
```

When executing `SELECT * FROM metrics_second` I always see the data, even after a minute or so, although the `default_time_to_live` property of the table is set to one second. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TTL for Cassandra counter column family. Is it supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752308/ttl-for-cassandra-counter-column-family-is-it-supported)

Comment: @RussS I'm trying to set it on the entire table, not just on a column

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Can't have a TTL on a counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @RussS confirmed, unfortunately Cassandra doesn't support TTL on tables or rows when there are counters.

Even if `default_time_to_live` is being set when creating the table and no error is being returned, Cassandra won't enforce the TTL.

Comment: FYI- I have created a JIRA ticket, asking for a warning or error message when TTLs are added to counter tables:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8678